# Android notification small icon

Tags: android, android-geofence

I am making an Geo Fencing App with notifications in Android Studio. But I have the problem that the notifications are not showing up.It says that it has no small icon but I did include that in my code.

> Error: 02-19 15:06:42.276 1260-1260/? E/NotificationService: Not
>   posting notification without small icon: Notification(channel=null
>   pri=2 contentView=null vibrate=[0] sound=null defaults=0x0 flags=0x91
>   color=0x00000000 vis=PRIVATE) 02-19 15:06:42.276 1260-1260/?
>   E/NotificationService: WARNING: In a future release this will crash
>   the app: com.koo.lightmanager 02-19 15:06:42.277 1260-1260/?
>   E/NotificationService: Error creating vibration waveform with pattern:
>   [0]

Code:

```
private void sendNotification(String title, String content) {
    Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(content);
    NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MapsActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

    manager.notify(new Random().nextInt(),notification);
}
```

Comment: have you tried using NotificationCompat.Builder instead?

Answer (score 0):

*Place the icon in Drawable folder, it will work*

```
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_round)
```

Comment: I made an icon in drawable but it still says that there is no small icon.

Comment: can you try with NotificationCompat.Builder